# Use of templates

Tags: c++, templates

I am learning C++ by programing a game and I am stuck with something: I have a code which is starting to be repetitive (I will add a number of other components) and I would like to improve it using templates (I guess), which I don't really know how to use.

Here's the code:

```
#include <memory>

#include "PositionComponent.h"
#include "VelocityComponent.h"

class ComponentManager
{
public:
    ComponentManager();

    void addComponent(Entity id, PositionComponent component);
    void addComponent(Entity id, VelocityComponent component);

private:
    std::map<Entity,std::shared_ptr<PositionComponent> > m_positionComponents;
    std::map<Entity,std::shared_ptr<VelocityComponent> > m_velocityComponents;
};
```

and

```
#include "ComponentManager.h"

ComponentManager::ComponentManager()
{

}

void ComponentManager::addComponent(Entity id, PositionComponent component)
{
    if (m_positionComponents.count(id) > 0)
    {
        Tools::log("couldn't add component");
    }
    // else if entity doesn't exist..
    else
    {
        m_positionComponents[id] = std::make_shared<PositionComponent>(component);
    }
}

void ComponentManager::addComponent(Entity id, VelocityComponent component)
{
    if (m_velocityComponents.count(id) > 0)
    {
        Tools::log("couldn't add component");
    }
    // else if entity doesn't exist..
    else
    {
        m_velocityComponents[id] = std::make_shared<VelocityComponent>(component);
    }
}
```

How to make that beautiful with templates?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe try Code Review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Feel like you are better off using inheritance, not templates

Comment: @awesomeyi Or static polymorphism, which includes templates again ;-) ...

Comment: Can't post right now, and I want to use templates here that's why I ask!

Comment: The most suitable choice will depend on whether its OK for different components to have the same Id - your code checks that components of the same type don't, but a position and a velocity could have the same ID. if you want no re-used IDs a map of some base component type might be better.

Comment: @ROX You may want different methods on the different types which can't be factored into a base class.  Then you would need to `dynamic_cast` (or `static_cast` and a custom `typeid`-like field) which undermines the point of the base class.

Comment: @Guy, as I said it depends on information we don't have here, and so it may or may not be suitable to use one collection. However if the uniqueness of id is required, then this is a case that dynamic_cast might be acceptable, e.g. if the user is providing the ID and the type they expect, then a failed dynamic cast can be checked for and the user given an error along the lines of "found a component with that ID, but its not the type you requested". I see so many unacceptable uses of dynamic_cast and I'm really not a fan of it, but if the fail case can and is suitably handled it's not so evil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using a template here is fine, and other options definitely exist.  Here's the template solution I would try:

```
template <class T>
void ComponentManager::addComponent(Entity id, T component)
{
    using MapType = std::map<Entity,std::shared_ptr<T> > &;
    auto allMaps = std::tie(m_positionComponents, m_velocityComponents);
    auto & tMap = std::get<MapType>(allMaps);
    if (tMap.count(id) > 0)
    {
        Tools::log("couldn't add component");
    }
    // else if entity doesn't exist..
    else
    {
        tMap[id] = std::make_shared<T>(component);
    }
}
```

This isn't tested at all, so I don't promise it will compile as is.

The overload of `std::get` used here requires `c++-14`.

Answer (score 0):

> How to make that beautiful with templates?

**Solution 1**

Add a `private` member function template to `ComponentManager`.

```
template <typename Component>
  void addComponent(Entity id,
                    Component component,
                    std::map<Entity,std::shared_ptr<Component> >& components)
  {
     if (components.count(id) > 0)
     {
        Tools::log("couldn't add component");
     }
     // else if entity doesn't exist..
     else
     {
        components[id] = std::make_shared<Component>(component);
     }
  }
```

and use it as:

```
void ComponentManager::addComponent(Entity id, PositionComponent component)
{
   this->addComponent(id, component, m_positionComponents);
}

void ComponentManager::addComponent(Entity id, VelocityComponent component)
{
   this->addComponent(id, component, m_velocityComponents);
}
```

The drawback of this approach is that for every type of `Component` you want to support, you'll need to add another `public` member function.

**Solution 2**

You can have only one `public` member function template to add components to the appropriate collection. Then you'll need to add code to get the right collection given the component type. One way to that would be to use a tag dispatch mechanism.

```
class ComponentManager
{
   public:
      ComponentManager();

      template <typename Component>
         void addComponent(Entity id, Component component)
         {
            std::map<Entity,std::shared_ptr<Component> >& components = getCollection(tag<Component>());
            if (components.count(id) > 0)
            {
               Tools::log("couldn't add component");
            }
            // else if entity doesn't exist..
            else
            {
               components[id] = std::make_shared<Component>(component);
            }
         }

   private:

      template <typename Component> struct tag {};

      std::map<Entity,std::shared_ptr<PositionComponent> >& getCollection(tag<PositionComponent>)
      {
         return m_positionComponents;
      }

      std::map<Entity,std::shared_ptr<PositionComponent> >& getCollection(tag<VelocityComponent>)
      {
         return m_velocityComponents;
      }

      std::map<Entity,std::shared_ptr<PositionComponent> > m_positionComponents;
      std::map<Entity,std::shared_ptr<VelocityComponent> > m_velocityComponents;
};
```

With this approach, you will still need to add another member function to the class for each type of `Component` you wish to support but they will be in the `private` section of the class, not `public`.

Comment: Passing the components collection as a parameter is somewhat cumbersome and is a risk. The collection to add to is always the member collection of that type. This requires exposing that collection and runs the risk of it being called with a different collection, one that's of the same type but is not the one in ComponentManager.

Comment: @ROX, the inner function would be private, and if you tried to pass the wrong component it would be a compile error and not a runtime error.

Comment: If its private you can't call it without a public version for each type which passes the correct collection. With that the class is back to having lots of similar functions for each type, which is exactly what the OP is trying to avoid.

Comment: @ROX, good points. As with many things in programming, there are more than one ways to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may create a template class that handles one generic type

```
template <typename T>
class ComponentManagerT
{
public:
    void addComponent(Entity id, T component)
    {
        if (m_components.count(id) > 0)
        {
            Tools::log("couldn't add component");
        }
        // else if entity doesn't exist..
        else
        {
            m_components[id] = std::make_shared<T>(component);
        }
    }

    // ...
private:
    std::map<Entity, std::shared_ptr<T>> m_components;
};
```

And a class to regroup all those managers

```
struct ComponentManager
{
    ComponentManagerT<PositionComponent> m_positionComponentManager;
    ComponentManagerT<VelocityComponent> m_velocityComponentManager;
};
```